# SELECTing from PostgreSQL tables, excluding an array item

Tags: arrays, postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I have a table with a column containing an array (lets call it `tags` for now).

How can I SELECT from that table all rows where the array column DOES NOT contain a certain tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM your_table
WHERE 'certain tag' != ALL (tags);
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this would be getting all ids where that tag is contained, then you can exclude those with a subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM foo
WHERE id NOT IN (
  SELECT id
  FROM foo
  WHERE tags @> ['specific-tag-here', 'other-tag-here']);
```

Comment: Maybe `WHERE not ( tags @> 'specific-tag-here')`? Much simpler and faster